# Can I use an iterable which reads a file in parallel_bulk?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Currently I have a function which reads a file in chunks, does some work (parsing, formating) and then `yeilds` the data in the format for the `elasticsearch` bulk loader.

Currently I'm using [`streaming_bulk`](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html), but I'm wondering is it possible to use [`parallel_bulk`](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html) instead?

Does [`parallel_bulk`](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html) mean that it sends data to `elasticsearch` concurrently, or does it mean that it calls the iterator conurrently?

**Basically, what exactly does `parallel_bulk` use the extra threads for?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer : `parallel_bulk` sends data to elasticsearch concurrently.

From the code snippet [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/blob/master/elasticsearch/helpers/__init__.py#L229): we see that `parallel_bulk` concurrently sends chunks of actions to elasticsearch. 
It uses pythons [multiprocessing.dummy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy) module.
The data is chunked and each chunk is passed on to the thread in pool